# angular serve in background

Tags: angular, github, github-actions

I have [this GitHub Actions workflow](https://github.com/gctools-outilsgc/gccollab-frontend/blob/4aa9eaabbf3b4a166f2b4a5d3ad6cb2a84eca25f/.github/workflows/e2e-test.yml).

For some reason, it only sometimes works. Otherwise, it fails with "server not ready" after its attempt limit. So the failure is somewhere between "Start http server" in the background, and "Wait for server to be ready." There's not much to fail.

From what I've seen, `npm start &` should work fine, but when I use that it prints nothing and doesn't seem to run, since the test browser can't connects to it.

I've tried all kinds of alternatives, ending on the instrumented version in the link, where it builds first (at least I can see the build passes) and serves the files statically. But It only sometimes works, printing Server is up and successfully running the tests.

I think it's otherwise straightforward, so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the wait time? Did you try emulating it on your local machine? How long does the server take to start on your local machine?

Comment: That seems like a _lot_ of code to have untested in a workflow script. It's much easier to use the same command in CI that you would locally - e.g. I often use `concurrently` and `wait-on` to manage an app and associated E2E tests: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2021/Apr/10/js-tdd-api.html#bonus.

Answer (score 0):

When you add `&` to a unix command, the process just starts in the background and your next command is executed immediately without waiting for the previous command to exit (more detailed answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86249/345849)). Since the server startup might take less or more time depending on the available resources, you sometimes reach the attempt limit in your tests before the server finished starting.

To get this to work, you will have to introduce some delay yourself. The most straight forward way would be to just wait a fixed amount of time. You could, of course, also add a more elaborate way of waiting (e.g. polling) like you did in your action. To debug what is going wrong, I would suggest to just wait a fixed amount of time for now and see if that works. If it works, the problem is not the action but your polling logic.

Answer (score 0):

````
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3.5.1
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: ng build
        run: |
          npm start &
          sleep 30  # on a good day

      - name: Run tests
        run: |
          cd haibun-e2e-tests
          npm ci
          npm run test home
    ```

and don't use act (local actions), apparently.
````